# How to query users who have empty first_name?

Tags: users, wp-user-query

So far I have tried these three options and all 3 of them are not working.

### Option 1

```
$options = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'first_name',
    'meta_value'   => '',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
);

$users = get_users( $options );
```

### Option 2

```
$options = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'first_name',
    'meta_value'   => null,
    'meta_compare' => '=',
);

$users = get_users( $options );
```

### Option 3

```
$options = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    )
);
$users = get_users( $options );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're searching for the `first_name` meta keys with **empty** string meta values:

```
$options = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    )
);
$users = get_users( $options );
```

that generates this kind of SQL query:

```
SELECT wp_users.* 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) 
WHERE 
    1=1 AND ( ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = '' ) ) 
ORDER BY user_login ASC
```

Note that

```
$options = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'first_name',
    'meta_value'   => '',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
);
$users = get_users( $options );
```

generates this kind of SQL query:

```
SELECT wp_users.* 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' ) 
ORDER BY user_login ASC ;
```

Comment: If user has not first name meta in data base then it not come with this query

Comment: true but I understand that OP is only searching for empty meta values, not non-existing ones, as the questions title says:: *How to query users who have empty first_name?* Otherwise +1 for your answer's suggestion if looking for empty meta value strings or non-existent meta keys  @PatelJignes

Comment: I was looking only for users who have a row in wp_usermeta table but with empty value. This answer worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 5):

Used below code. it return all data which has not first_name key in data base  or which has empty first_name

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'first_name',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'first_name',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    )
);
$users = get_users( $args );
var_dump($users);exit;
```

Comment: I don't want to retrieve users who don't have the meta key, but anyways thanks for the answer.